# require_once in PHP is printing in mobile devices

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a PHP file in my server which is working well on desktop devices. It's basically only this code snippet:

```
<?php
    require_once('wp-load.php');

    global $wpdb;

    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM view_posts_map LIMIT 10");
?>
```

(the rest of the content prints the results on the HTML page.)

It happens that on desktop browsers everything works perfectly! But in mobile devices such as my Motorola 3rd G it all messes up and the `'wp-load.php'` is simply printed in the HTML code. Which makes no sense, since the PHP is processed in server side and there's no branch of code regarding the request device.

I tested in a few other mobile devices and the HTML is all messed up while in desktop browsers the HTML is clean and showing the contents as it should be.

**To try to figure out what's happening I created an empty file with the following body:**

```
<?php echo 'a'; ?>
<?php include('./wp-load.php'); ?>
<?php echo 'b'; ?>
```

There's nothing else on the file.

In Windows Google Chrome this page prints `ab`, in my device Google Chrome it prints `a‹Kùï¾q`

Comment: Going to need more info to answer this. Are you redirecting? What mobile conditions are in place?

Comment: Sounds like there's a server side compression that's beating the PHP parser. Does a simple `<?= "Hello world" ?>` work?

Comment: @Mike No, that's the weird thing... there no mobile conditions... the only PHP code in the page is that. And it works well on desktop.

Comment: @Mooseman yes, the Hello World is working.

Comment: The issue has to be server related. It compiles differently depending on header? It seems very very very odd. Please elaborate on server details.

Comment: If you use the Chrome DevTools and [emulate a device](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) what do you get?

Comment: @Xorifelse Exactly... very odd. I lost my whole day trying to fix that in a lot of different solutions.

Comment: @Mooseman Yes, right now I'm using the Chrome tools to see the source code generated and there's a lot of � and other strange characters on the same place the required_once is called.

Comment: Well, � usually refers to fetching data from a database without using UTF-8 (charset) parameter to connect with the database.

Comment: @Xorifelse the database access is doing good because when I put the required_once before the <html> it messes up the HTML with all the characters but in the end of the file I can see the results being printed.

Comment: Try making a desktop request from your device, the same result?

Comment: @JoseRojas How do I do that?

Comment: Mobile browser of Android or Chrome in options (part top right, 3 dots vertically), has the option "Request desktop site"

Comment: @JoseRojas Thanks, Jose, same error with or without this option.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason it was a problem with the .php file encoding. After creating a new file by copying wp-load.php and changing its content to match their encoding, everything went well in both devices.